# In a submit.php, how to have the script wait until dbase returns a value being recorded

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

The idea is to have a php script wait until Paypal transaction is completed (and recorded in a Dbase via Paypal Ipn).

The wait should happened at this query:

Here is my code to retreive data from the Dbase (it works well)

```
$PaypalStatus = "SELECT payment_status FROM al_paypal WHERE ((item_number='" .$No . "') || (item_number='" .$NoGift . "')) ";
$query3 = mysql_query($PaypalStatus);
$row3 = mysql_fetch_row($query3);
$PaypalStatus = $row3[0];
```

I like to force the script to wait until the query returns data (it could take a few minutes for the transaction to be recorded).
I don't know if it can be done and how.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry, just dont understand the question. (p.s IPN can take hours)

Comment: I rephrased the question in the hope it is clearer.

Comment: somewhere in the db you should record that paypal confirmed the payment, you should query where that is the case.

Comment: Yes it is done, but I do not know how to have the script wait until it is the case. It will be recorded sooner or later. Payment and script are launched at the same time.

Comment: why not have the script trigged byt the IPN handler when the confirmation comes through

Comment: I tried several solutions, one, via postMessage without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

1. Create another page (`get-status.php`) that returns status of the db record of a given `item_number` (the `item_number` is passed as a post or get based on your requirement)
2. In your payment confirmation/status page, show a loading icon and/or a message to the user saying "Payment status pending",
3. In the payment confirmation/status page, do an ajax call to `get-status.php` with `item_number`, and set js timeout to check the status.
4. If you get a status from *Paypal*, your subsequent ajax call get that status then hide the loading icon and/or the message and show the payment status or success information whatever to the user.

I have implemented that for Paypal payment system and working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, it looks to me very complicated.